# How to create a very limited linux user

Tags: user-accounts, user-permissions

I need a user in my linux machine to execute some commands in `.bash_profile`. But I don't want this user can have access to `sftp`, `ftp` and any other protocols. Also any commands can't be executed except some in `.bash_profile`.

So I want to create a user who can't use any protocol except ssh and can't execute any commands except commands from .bash_profile. What should I do?

**Update:**

I have tried `rbash`, but it seems that I can get out of it by typing `bash`.

```
[root@centos-7 ~]# which rbash
/usr/bin/rbash
[root@centos-7 ~]# ls
a  anaconda-ks.cfg
[root@centos-7 ~]# cd a
[root@centos-7 a]# pwd
/root/a
[root@centos-7 a]# cd
[root@centos-7 ~]# rbash
[root@centos-7 ~]# cd a
rbash: cd: restricted
[root@centos-7 ~]# bash
[root@centos-7 ~]# cd a
[root@centos-7 a]# pwd
/root/a
```

Comment: The first one should include configuring advanced routing/firewalling in Linux. You can limit traffic on per uid/pid etc. You might want to consider L7 firewall as well. The other one is a bit tricky. Check out `rbash` for starters.

Comment: @KonradGajewski Thank for your advice.I will try the firewall settings for the first protocol limitation. For the second one, I have tried  `rbash`. The problem is I can get out of `rbash` by typing `bash` in rbash. I also tried set `PATH`  in user's `.bash_profile` to a empty directory, but it seems I can still use some commands such as cd, ls.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `sudoers`?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create the restricted shell.

cp /bin/bash /bin/rbash

2. Modify the target user for the shell as restricted shell

While creating user:

```
# useradd -s /bin/rbash localuser
```

For existing user:

```
# usermod -s /bin/rbash localuser
```

For more detailed information on this, please check the KBase Article 8349

Then the user localuser is chrooted and can't access the links outside his home directory /home/localuser

3. Create a directory under /home/localuser/, e.g. programs

   mkdir /home/localuser/programs
4. Now if you check, the user localuser can access all commands which he/she has allowed to execute. These commands are taken from the environmental PATH variable which is set in /home/localuser/.bash_profile. Modify it as follows.

   cat /home/localuser/.bash_profile
    .bash_profile

   Get the aliases and functions
   if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   . ~/.bashrc
   fi
    User specific environment and startup programs
   PATH=$HOME/programs
   export PATH

Here the PATH variable is set to ~/programs directory, as /usr/local/bin is binded to /home/username/bin and /bin is binded to /home/username/bin so replacing that.

5. Now after logging with the username localuser, user cant run a simple command too. The output will be like this,

   [localuser@example ~]$ ls
   -rbash: ls: command not found
   [localuser@example ~]$ less file1
   -rbash: less: command not found
   [localuser@example ~]$ clear
   -rbash: clear: command not found
   [localuser@example ~]$ date
   -rbash: date: command not found
   [localuser@example ~]$ ping redhat.com
   -rbash: ping: command not found
6. Now create the softlinks of commands which are required for user localuser to execute in the directory /home/localuser/programs

   ln -s /bin/date /home/localuser/programs/
    ln -s /bin/ls /home/localuser/programs/
    ll /home/localuser/programs/
   total 8
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 17 15:53 date -> /bin/date
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 17 15:43 ls -> /bin/ls

Here examples of date and ls commands has been taken

7. Again login with user localuser and try to execute the commands.

   [localuser@example ~]$ date
   Mon Oct 17 15:55:45 IST 2011
   [localuser@example ~]$ ls
   file1 file10 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9 programs
   [localuser@example ~]$ clear
   -rbash: clear: command not found
8. One more step can be added to restrict the user for making any modifications in their .bash_profile , as users can change it.

Run the following command to make the user localuser's .bash_profile file as immutable so that root/localuser can't modify it until root removes immutable permission from it.

```
# chattr +i /home/localuser/.bash_profile
```

To remove immutable tag,

```
# chattr -i /home/localuser/.bash_profile
```

Make file .bash_profile as immutable so that user localuser can't change the environmental paths.